# Evaluating trigonometric expressions in Java

Tags: java, function

How to insert a trigonometric function in the console for further work with it?? For example, sin(x) = 2x + 3log (y) or something like this.I think.. I need to enter an expression as a string, and then it is processed as. But how?

Comment: Have you searched the site or spent some time on google looking for APIs that already do this?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for. I can not figure out exactly how to formulate my request.

Comment: You could enter it as an infix expression and parse it out from there onto some sort of stack and then deal with computation.

Comment: @Mike See my answer for an existing library that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/apidocs/index.html)

We have used this library extensively in one of our projects for solving the exact same problem that you are facing.

```
Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
                .variables("x", "y")
                .build()
                .setVariable("x", 2.3)
                .setVariable("y", 3.14);
        double result = e.evaluate();
```

In your particular case, you can ask the user for the following inputs in the console and build your expression using these inputs :

1. Enter the expression to evaluate. This will become the argument to the ExpressionBuilder constructor.
2. Enter the Strings that represent the variables in the expression. This will become the input to the variables method. You can add these Strings as keys to a Map which can be used in the next step.
3. Enter the value of each variable. This will become the input to the setVariable methods. You could collect all the variable values as values in the Map created in the above step. You can iterate over the map and call setVariable(key,value) so that you don't need to know how many variables are present in an expression before hand.

Comment: Looks good, but where you can see the instructions for installing the package?

Comment: @Mike Did you try to search exp4j in google? You find a link to download the jar as soon as you visit the first link that pops up. You can add this jar as project dependency. If you don't know how to use external jars in a java program/project, post a new question on stackoverflow for the same. I believe I have answered your immediate question.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/)**. Example(from the link):

```
Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
        .variables("x", "y")
        .build()
        .setVariable("x", 2.3)
        .setVariable("y", 3.14);
double result = e.evaluate();
```

Another option is **[Javaluator](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/)**. See the link for example.

And there's **[EvalX](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx)**. See below example(from the link):

```
Expression expression = new Expression("1+1/3");
result = expression.eval():
expression.setPrecision(2);
result = expression.eval():
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition, I recently found out you can separate exp4j ExpressionBuilder into two parts and add values to the variables in a for loop, you can find may examples at this website https://github.com/fasseg/exp4j/blob/master/src/test/java/net/objecthunter/exp4j/ExpressionBuilderTest.java

```
ExpressionBuilder e = new ExpressionBuilder("x^2")
 .variable("x")
 .build();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  e.setVariable("x", i);
  System.out.println("x^2 = " + e.evaluate());
}
```